# Visual Studio get stuck always during app deployment on azure

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

[image]Visual Studio get stuck always during app deployment on azure.

9:33:26 AM PowerAppsTestNode: Creating zip package...
9:33:26 AM PowerAppsTestNode: Zip package size: 649 kB

And after several minutes of waiting:
azure deployment failed, reason: socket hang up

Note: app is just simple nodejs express sample app for testing.

Do you have pls any idea what to do. I am stuck on this for few days now and was not able to find any viable solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer, but maybe this could help another person.

So I had the same problem, and digging a little more in the logs I discovered this:

Command 'starter.cmd "C:\home\site\d ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 60 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.\r

So it seems to be a problem with the amount of time the server wait for inactivity.

To change the waiting time of the azure app service go to  Azure Portal > your web app> Configure tab and add a New Application Setting SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT and set it value higher than 60 (default) maybe 600, so the server awaits 10 minutes instead of 1.

After i did that it worked, Hope it works for you